How to extract parts of a linq fluent nHibernate selection into a function?
This is my fluent nHibernate select:
var sprachfoerderkraefteContent = (from sprachfoerderkraft in Session.MainDBSession.Query<MITARBEITER>()
                                   from mitarbeiter_akt in Session.MainDBSession.Query<MITARBEITER_AKT>()
                                   where (mitarbeiter_akt.MIA_KEY_AKT == m_akt.Akt.LFD) &&
                                         (mitarbeiter_akt.MIA_KEY_MA_SPRACHFOERDERKRAFT == sprachfoerderkraft.LFD)
                                         &&
                                         (!filterForKGJ ||
                                         ((mitarbeiter_akt.MIA_VON == null) || (mitarbeiter_akt.MIA_VON <= kindergartenjahrBis )) &&
                                         ((mitarbeiter_akt.MIA_BIS == null) || (mitarbeiter_akt.MIA_BIS >= kindergartenjahrVon )))
                                   orderby mitarbeiter_akt.MIA_BIS != null,
                                           mitarbeiter_akt.MIA_BIS,
                                           sprachfoerderkraft.MA_NAMF,
                                           sprachfoerderkraft.MA_NAMV
                                   select new MITARBEITERAlsSprachfoerderkraft()
                                   {
                                       Sprachfoerderkraft = sprachfoerderkraft,
                                       Verbindung = mitarbeiter_akt,
                                   }).ToList();

As I need a part multible times I want to extract this part and put it into an own function so I can reuse it. So this part:
 (!filterForKGJ ||
 ((mitarbeiter_akt.MIA_VON == null) || (mitarbeiter_akt.MIA_VON <= kindergartenjahrBis )) &&
 ((mitarbeiter_akt.MIA_BIS == null) || (mitarbeiter_akt.MIA_BIS >= kindergartenjahrVon )))

should be in an function.
Im happy about every hint.
